# Monitor incoming data from sensor via Nagios

Tags: nagios

I am working on a project where we have multiple sensors installed and they generate data at different sampling rates.

Is it possible to use a Nagios plugin to check whether data is coming or not for a particular sensor or device?.

If it is possible, then which plugin could be used for such a purpose? I have searched through the Nagios plugin site and the internet but couldn't find anything that seemed related to this.

there are different Sensors which generate data in Ascii format, so sensors are the main sources of data generation, then we are using rsync to synchronized this data into our central MySQL database. and each sensor has different sampling rate. .for example temperature sensor generate data every 2 minutes and humidity sensor generate data every 5 minutes. this data is stored in text file by using rsync. ..I want to monitor whether data is coming every 2 minutes or 5 minutes depending on source sampling rate. 
So custom nagios script will help me to know about missing data state.

Can someone point out a useful tutorial about custom plugins/scripts to deal with such a situation? (I am new to Nagios and I would be grateful for any help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own plugin:

[How To : Create Nagios Plugin Using a BASH Script](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/06/how-to-create-nagios-plugin-using-bash-script.html?m=1)

*If you edit your original question with more details on how data is gathered from the sensors, I might be able to help you with `bash` if you need.*

Edit: Final answer
Enjoy that: =)
Any problem you can tell to me

```
#!/bin/bash
# How to execute ./sensor.sh tem_sensor
HOUR=$(date +%H)
MIN=$(date +%M)

# Directory where they are sensor directorys
DIR=/home/robbin/Desktop/sensor_collection/
# Name of selected sensor
SENSOR=$1
# Name of sensor's directoris
SENSORS=(tem_sensor tem_sensor2 tem_sensor3)

# Loop in every folder
for i in ${SENSORS[@]}
do
        # We only want the specified sensor so we will skip until we found it
        if [[ $SENSOR != $i ]]; then continue ; fi
        # You take the hour and minute value from last file
        LHOUR=$(ls -lrt $DIR/$i| tail -n1 | awk '{ print $8}' | awk -F ':' '{ print $1}')
        LMIN=$(ls -lrt $DIR/$i | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $8}' | awk -F ':' '{ print $2}')
        # We calculate the diferences
        let FHOUR=($HOUR - $LHOUR)
        let FMIN=($MIN - $LMIN)
        # I normally put echo to "debug if i need"
        # echo "------------- SENSOR $i ---------------"
        # echo "LHOUR : $LHOUR LMIN : $LMIN"
        # echo "HOUR : $HOUR MIN : $MIN"
        # echo "FHOUR : $FHOUR FMIN : $FMIN"
        # echo "---------------------------------------"
        # if the diference is greater than 2
        if [[ $FMIN -gt 02 ]]; then
                echo "WARNING - More than 2 minutes withouth recieving data"
                exit 1 # We put warning!
        # Else if it is not more than 2
        # We check if we have an hour of diference!
        elif [[ $FMIN -gt 04 ]]; then
                echo "CRITICAL - More than 4 minutes withouth recieving data"
                exit 2 # We put Red alert!
        else
                echo "OK - We recieve data"
                exit 0 # Green alert if we dont have problems
        fi
done
echo "UNKNOW - Sensor not found"
exit 3
# If we got unkwnow (Grey alert)
# with exit 3 it's because you finished the loop
# and you shouldn't, that will be because you misspelled the sensor name
```

Comment: Sensor generate data in Ascii format and then we are using rsync to synchronized this data into our central MySQL database. and each sensor has different sampling rate. .for example temperature sensor generate data every 2 minutes. this data is stored in text file by using rsync. ..I want to monitor whether data is coming every 2 minutes or not. for this purpose i had to write a custom script in nagios. If any tip or help. it would be great.

Comment: for example there are scripts written in C for each sensor to generate data. .......but i am interested in knowing whether the data is being generated every 2 minutes for temperature sensor or not.

Comment: So there are diferent sources which are the sensors. Every filename has the same name? Or can be placed in diferent folders to diferenciate the source? Then the bash script only needs to check that the last generated file was created under 2 minutes ago. Also you can configure to check every sensor with a single parameter in the bash script i think

Comment: sorry for late response. yes sensors are sources, and they are placed in different folders to differentiate between sensors.  can you help me to give a simple example for one sensor or point out any site from where i can get idea because i am new to bash and i didn't use it before.  e.g how can i use bash script to check that the last generated file was created 2 minutes ago.

Comment: and I am looking for exactly the same thing. to estimate whether data is being generated every 2 minutes, 5 minutes etc depending on different sensors to give overview of missing data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In "DIR=/home", I had to give the path of the file which is being updated every 2 minutes or 5 minutes. right?. and here "SENSOR=$1" the name of the sensor ,e.g "SENSOR=$1temperature_sensor" . right?. .  .....................but if i had two or more sensors, eng humidity sensor, pressure sensor. How can I add multiple path of sensors and their respective names?. .

Comment: I will try this solution and I hope it will solve my problem, and then i will come back here to accept your solution as answer. thanks a lot

Comment: No. DIR is where sensor directories are allocated. It wasnt the idea? or maybe i missunderstood you

Comment: you understood correctly. each sensor has different directory. I mean that how can I specify 2 or more sensor to check their data generation rates. mean how can i specify 2 or 3 sensors.

Comment: You just launch the nagios plugin with diferent parametters. So you will need to define every sensor check command in commands.cfg

Comment: thanks. I will come back here after trying this solution.

Comment: so i keep the sensor variable same like this and run script according to your suggestion, but same error i am getting. ......................DIR="/home/robbin/Desktop/sensor_collection/"...........SENSOR=$1............SENSORS=(sensor1). . and i run script as  ./sensor.sh temp.dat. ........(sensor.sh is the bash script.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63491/discussion-between-angel-porlan-and-robbin).